# Using shortcode to stop post content from displaying

Tags: shortcode, the-content

Is there any way to use **shortcode** to block the display of the post content?

What I want is to use the shortcode to pull the post content directly from the database, manipulate it, and then display it with the shortcode.

But if I do this, the post content displays twice. Once as it prints normally and again when the shortcode displays it.

Is there any way to use shortcode to stop `the_content()` from executing?

Comment: How do you create your shortcode?

Comment: Where is your shortcode code and what is the context for which you are showing this content? `single.php`, `page.php` etc... or something else?

Comment: The shortcode is in a single post. The shortcode itself is being registered by a custom plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use of shortcode, you can get the post content, format them the way you want and display them later.

You can use [get_the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) function; which will just retrieve post content in a variable.

```
    $raw_input = get_the_content();
/*process your content here and store the result in variable
eg.*/ 
$raw_input = str_replace("No", "Yes", $raw_input);
print $raw_input;
```

This will print the processed content and you can just comment out `the_content()` function in your `single.php`.

Comment: Just curious but could you do this in a way so you wouldn't have to edit the theme files?